# How to synchronize access of shared data between tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-core

I'm using .net core and tasks for some parallel works, basically it is like two producers and one consumers, two tasks will write data and the consumer will read it, in tranditioanal .net code, these are done by threads, I could use `Semaphore` or `Mutex` or `EventHandle` for synchronization between the threads, but with new task based code, I read that I can no longer use these, because there is no guarantee that an async function will resume on the same thread after await, so how should I sync between different tasks?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is `Mutex.OpenExisting`, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how should I sync between different tasks?

Since you have a producer/consumer system, you can use [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx), which acts as an async-compatible producer/consumer queue.

In the more general sense of coordination primitive replacements, see [my AsyncEx.Coordination library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx). Or you can [build your own](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/). The only one built-in to .NET is `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try AsyncEx, all the original synchronization primitives are in System.Threading, and there is nothing similar was added in System.Threading.Tasks, does that means this scenario is rare in TAP? Or when there is need to sync, one should use old threads instead of tasks?

Comment: You do end up needing to synchronize less often with TAP. IMO this is partially due to asynchronous code naturally being functional, and partially due to the types of problems it's commonly applied to. In many common scenarios, what used to be accomplished using threading can now be accomplished without it.